# User flair with theme clean won't update rep

Tags: support, reputation, flair

Is this a bug or just a server glitch/delay?

I use the flair in my gmail signature and noticed that the clean theme didn't get updated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be up-to-date now, so it was probably just a server delay (**edit**: or a local caching problem, based on the comments):

[image: OP's clean flair]

Comment: Not really... my current rep is 9,844. I'm still seeing 9,813 in the image you included in your answer.

Comment: @Leniel Sounds like a caching problem then; it's right on my end

Comment: Oh... I thought that could be the problem.

Comment: @Leniel, http://i.imgur.com/cxnuq.png It is definitely a caching issue.

Comment: @jjnguy: crazy thing... I'm still seeing 9,813 in my end.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for letting me use your answer to upload a pic.

Comment: @Leniel, did you try a hard refresh? (ctrl+f5)

Comment: @Leniel Go to http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/114029.png?theme=clean and ctrl/shift/whatever+F5 to reload the image

Comment: I'm using Mac OS 10.6.6 and Firefox 3.6.13. The hard refresh didn't solve.

Comment: I tried it in Chrome and I still get 9,813. I also tried in Safari and I get 9,813.

Comment: @Leniel Are you behind something that caches besides your browser? Try http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/114029.png?theme=clean&foo=bar

Comment: Not that I know of. Why then the other flair tastes are being updated? As I said I just use the clean theme in my Gmail signature. If that's the problem, I really would like to know.

Comment: @Michael: I tried this URL http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/114029.png?theme=clean&foo=bar with the additional &foo=bar parameter. This didn't solve.